# Why there is no Nullable<T>.Equals(T value) method?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

Let's start with a very simple piece of code:

```
decimal d = 2;

Console.WriteLine("d == 2 = {0}", d == 2);
Console.WriteLine("d == (decimal)2 = {0}", d == (decimal)2);
Console.WriteLine("d.Equals(2) = {0}", d.Equals(2));
Console.WriteLine("d.Equals((decimal)2) = {0}", d.Equals((decimal)2));
```

The result is 4xtrue. Now, let's change  a type of a variable *d* to *decimal?*:

```
decimal? d = 2;
```

This time the result will be *True, True, False, True*. The explanation of this situation is quite easy. *Equals* method is implemented as follows for *Nullable<T>* type:

```
public override bool Equals(object other)
{
    if (!this.HasValue)
    {
        return (other == null);
    }
    if (other == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return this.value.Equals(other);
}
```

If *this* has a value and *other* parameter is not null then *Decimal.Equals(object value)* will be called. *Decimal.Equals(object value)* method works in this way, that if *value* parameter  is not *decimal* then the result will be always *false*.

It seems to me that the current implementation is not intuitive and I wonder why *Nullable<T>* doesn't provide developers with generic version of *Equals* method e.g.:

```
public bool Equals(T other)
{
    if (!this.HasValue)
        return false;

    return this.value.Equals(other);
}
```

Was it done on purpose or is it an omission?

Comment 1:

A brief comment to be clear. I suggested that *Nullable<T>* should have two *Equals* methods i.e.: *public override bool Equals(object other)* and *public bool Equals(T other)*

Comment: I don't see how they could provide that. `T` is not necessarily `IEquatable<T>`

Comment: Shouldn't it be a `public bool Equals(T? other)` method? Otherwise, given declarations `decimal? d1, d2;`, `d1.Equals(d2)` would be invalid.

Comment: @hvd I think he wants an additional overload. So your example goes to the `Equal(object)` overload. But a generic Equals doesn't make sense unless you also have one on `T`.

Comment: @mikez `T` is implicitly convertible to `T?`, so would still be callable without a specific overload for `T`. And without an overload for `T?`, calling `decimal?.Equals` with an argument of `int?` would still have the same problem this question asks about, as it would resolve to `decimal?.Equals(object)` and not convert the contained `int` value to type `decimal`.

Comment: theres also an connect entry from 2011, but the state is closed!! http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/679706/nullable-t-should-implement-iequatable-nullable-t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of writing `(decimal)2` you can write `2m` (will use that in the following).

When you use the `==` operator, no boxing occurs. The C# compiler will choose the pre-defined overload (i.e. the overload defined in the C# Language Specification; this is not necessarily a real .NET method) of `operator ==` which matches best.

There are overloads:

```
operator ==(int x, int y);
operator ==(decimal x, decimal y);
```

There are no "mixed" overloads like `operator ==(decimal x, int y);`. Because an implicit conversion exists from `int` to `decimal`, your literal `2` is converted to `2m` implicitly when you use `==`.

With `Equals`, in some situations **boxing** occurs. You don't need nullables for that. To give examples, all of these calls:

```
object.Equals(2, 2m);
object.Equals(2m, 2);
((object)2).Equals(2m);
((object)2m).Equals(2);
(2).Equals((object)2m);
(2m).Equals((object)2);
(2).Equals(2m);
```

return `false`! "Two" of type `Int32` is not equal to "two" of type `Decimal`.

Only when method overloading leads to a conversion between `int` and `decimal` will the result be `true`. For example:

```
(2m).Equals(2);  // true
```

So while an extra overload of `Equals` *could* be added to `Nullable<>`, the behavior you describe is not really related to `Nullable<>`.

Answer (score 1):

Although I like these questions, they can only really be answered by those on the design team responsible for the type. An obvious workaround is to access the `Value` that is `T` and use the `Equals` of that.

My best guess is that it would probably force all `T` to be `IEquatable<T>`, in order to generically access `Equals<T>` on a given type. This would work for the core value types, but other .NET structs wouldn't necessarily implement that interface and `enum` types don't.

I suppose it could be done via type checking / casting, but this then comes a lot of legwork versus the caller simply doing: `myNullable.GetValueOrDefault().Equals()`.

You can make an extension method to do this task, to get it to call the method you need to specify the generic argument explicitly (otherwise the compiler calls `Equals(object)`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double? d = null;

        Console.WriteLine(d.Equals<double>(0.0));

        d = 0.0;

        Console.WriteLine(d.Equals<double>(0.0));

        Console.Read();
    }
}

public static class NullableExtensions
{
    public static bool Equals<T>(this T? left, T right) where T : struct, IEquatable<T>
    {
        if (!left.HasValue)
            return false;

        return right.Equals(left.Value);
    }
}
```

<sub>[I've asked a question about why this call is needed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736146/extension-method-on-nullablet-not-called-unless-explicit)</sub>

Turns out the reason for having to force it down into the extension method is due to the compiler implementation only using extension methods if no suitable method exists, in this case `Equals(object)` is considered more suitable than `Equals<T>(T)` as the latter is an extension method. It's in the spec.

Comment: You: _My best guess is that it would probably force all `T` to be `IEquatable<T>`, in order to generically access `Equals<T>` on a given type._ Not really. The method the Original Poster suggests could be pasted directly into the `Nullable<>` source, an it would work. If `Nullable<>` had both overloads as true instance methods, overload resolution would have to choose between the two. It would make the situations entirely analogous to the example `(2m).Equals(2)` from my answer in this thread. Here there are two overloads to choose from, and the one that takes a `decimal` is most specific.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen His code wouldn't work as is because the only available method would have been `Equals(object)`, to get it to choose a type-specific version, you need to constrain `T` somehow, or cast manually and manually call the relevant `Equals`. I also said "probably", but as you say this isn't strictly true, you could test to see if the type implements `IEquatable<T>` and cast without the generic constraint.

Comment: I am being misunderstood. With the extra overload from the original question, the extra overload would be chosen by overload resolution. Then the `2` argument would be implicitly converted to `2m`. You are right it would end up calling `Equals(object)` (actually `ValueType.Equals(object)`), but that would be fine, because `2m` and `2m` _are_ equal as objects. Conclusion: Yes, his code would "work" as is.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Oh I see, but you wouldn't get any of the benefits of calling based on knowing `T`, so boxing would still occur. His code would work as is given the ability to reimplement `Nullable<T>`, whereas my code works as a workaround.