# Extension method on Nullable<T> not called unless generic type is set explicitly

Tags: c#, extension-methods

While investigating another question: "[Why there is no Nullable<T>.Equals(T value) method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735404/why-there-is-no-nullablet-equalst-value-method/18735626#18735626)" I made an extension method on `Nullable<T>` that exposed a generic `Equals<T>(T)` method:

```
public static class NullableExtensions
{
    public static bool Equals<T>(this T? left, T right) where T : struct, IEquatable<T>
    {
        if (!left.HasValue)
            return false;

        return right.Equals(left.Value);
    }
}
```

However, calling it like so:

```
double? d = null;
d.Equals(0.0);
```

Calls into the base `Equals(object)` with boxing, as you can see in the IL:

```
IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ldloca.s d
IL_0003: initobj valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<float64>
IL_0009: ldloca.s d
IL_000b: ldc.r8 0.0
IL_0014: box [mscorlib]System.Double
IL_0019: constrained. valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<float64>
IL_001f: callvirt instance bool [mscorlib]System.Object::Equals(object)
```

If I change the call to explicitly state the generic type:

```
d.Equals<double>(0.0);
```

It calls my extension method:

```
IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ldloca.s d
IL_0003: initobj valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<float64>
IL_0009: ldloc.0
IL_000a: ldc.r8 0.0
IL_0013: call bool ConsoleApplication8.NullableExtensions::Equals<float64>(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<!!0>, !!0)
```

Why does the compiler not choose the extension method over the `Equals(object)` method?

Is it because I've just chosen a poor method name of `Equals<T>(T)` where it isn't actually a true override of `Equals` and not part of the inheritance look-up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why does the compiler not choose the extension method over the Equals(object) method?

Extension methods are *only* considered if there are no other alternatives. It's a fall-back - it's not part of normal overload resolution for instance methods. This isn't specific to nullable types - it's part of normal extension method invocation.

From section 7.6.5.2 of the spec:

> In a method invocation of one of the forms
>
> [...]
>
> **if the normal processing of the invocation finds no applicable methods**, an attempt is made to process the construct as an extension method invocation.

(Emphasis mine.)

Comment: Ah, suspected something along these lines, hence the need to explicitly state it up front. Not sure whether to be happy or sad that it took me longer to make the question than it did to get it answered :-)